# Calculating rotation constant of carbon monoxide ($\mathrm{CO}$) from its rotational-vibrational spectrum

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, molecular-dynamics

Given that the rotational-vibrational spectrum of carbon monoxide $\mathrm{CO}$ as well as the positions of the peaks $R_J$ and $P_J$ of the $R$- and the $P$-Branch.

With this information, one can calculate the rotation constant $B_1$ and the elongation constant $D_1$ of $\mathrm{CO}$ in the first excited state by fitting the measured data via the formula

$$R_J - P_J = -D_1(2J+1)^3+(2B_1-3D_1)(2J+1)$$

**My question:**

How can one calculate the rotation constant $B_2$ and the elongation constant $D_2$ of $\mathrm{CO}$ in the second excited state?

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: I tried using the same formula for $B_2$ and $D_2$ for the branches corresponding to the vibrational state $n=2$.